# How to efficiently cache very large sets of IDs from database?

Tags: php, caching

Suppose we have table 'Items' with millions of IDs (integer, primary key)
Users can see items at url like '/goods/ID/'

So in my controller I need a way to know if given ID really exists.

1. I dont want to access database at all because of high load.
2. Pure in-memory cache (like memcache) don't fit here, because lack of persistency.

Is there a solution which give me fast reliable access to whole set of IDs?

Comment: if accessing your db to check if a value exists = high load. you have far bigger issues.

Comment: how frequently the set if IDs changes?

Comment: Dagon, I get your point, but anyway my question remains the same :)

Marek, it changes frequently, but most of changes are DELETEs. So IDs range is very sparse.

Comment: it's what the db is for, its why the data is there, why ignore that fact?

Comment: Checking if a primary key exists in a database is a matter of a lookup in an index. Checking if that value exists in a cache will not be much faster; you only avoid the database protocol overhead, the actual search is likely of similar cost.

Comment: I use DB extensively in background scripts and admin panel. But I just dont like even to connect DB in public part of high-load site. Because it can give me much problems with scalability. Because I've heard about highload projects where 99% of requests dont use DB. And I wanna reveal the techniques used in them.

Comment: lanzz, yes you get my point - avoid db connection overhead at all.

Comment: only if you are doing it wrong, most sites access dbs for ever single page request with out issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would cache ranges to minimise the amount of stored IDs, it might be helpful if you decide in using SQL with caching.

Comment: Good thought. However, in my case IDs are very sparse, so there will be a bunch of ranges.

By the way, you've inspired me to a crazy solution: to maintain a solid ID range with no gaps. This can be done by using "old" unused IDs for new records. This requires some additional work, but as a result I should store in cache only one number - last ID created.

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know you have this possibility, this management will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Memcache is ok - If ID is not cached, check with Database. We use Memcached for 10 million users apps...

Or maybe [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) is what you are looking for?

Comment: What about so-called 'nosql' solutions? I dont know much about them. May they solve my task, completely replacing memcache & database?

Comment: Looking for your ids in a nosql database will not be faster than looking in a relational database.